# Rational curves through a fixed number of points

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, projective-geometry

Let us fix two positive integers $d$, and $N$. Can we determine a third integer $n$ such that given $n$ general points $p_1,...,p_n\in\mathbb{P}^N$ there exists a unique rational curve of degree $d$ thorugh $p_1,...,p_n$?

For example, when $d=N$ it is well known that $n = N+3$.

Comment: That's the only case, though.  Because if you have, say, 5 general points in P^3, there's no conic through them because they're not coplanar, but there's more than one cubic that go through them because those need 6 points.

Comment: This I know. However, what if we take $8$ general points in $\mathbb{P}^3$, is it true that there is a unique rational curve of degree $4$ passig through them?

Comment: I think there are $4$ rational curves of degree $4$ passing through $8$ general points in $\mathbb{P}^3$. For a general method for computing these numbers see, for example, section 9 of the article (http://arxiv.org/abs/alg-geom/9608011).

Comment: Ahh, I missed that you didn't say "normal." As @ulrich noted, it looks like uniqueness might not be doable, but there might be a number where it's finite.